# How to properly use ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets to calculate Form Responses

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have responses in column D that are in HH:MM:SS format that I need to convert to seconds as the responses come in. I understand that doing an array in another column in Sheets is the proper solution, however, I can't seem to figure out the syntax. Here is the formula not in an array: "=IF(D2="","",(sum(hour(D2)*3600,minute(D2)*60,second(D2))))". Can somebody help with how to make this formula into an ArrayFormula?

I tried a few different versions but they were not even close I imagine.

Comment: Re-read what you had, so deleted the suggestion as I thought you wanted just the seconds, but you want all the time from this date to another date?  Ooof .. okay well, man I hope Google supports the tried and true method of converting dates to UNIXTIMPSTAMP format so that for example the value as I wrote this was 1701476710.  a few hours later it will be 1701484575 so SIMPLE math of subtraction and you are done!  Its literally the best system for this, trying to think about dates and leap years and all that is annoying, so turn it into simple integer math!

Comment: Ok .. so researched for you, its not built in but the formula to convert to that is :
=(A1 - DATE(1970, 1, 1)) * 86400

As the count was started in 1970 and it goes up for decades until about 18 years from now it runs out of digits.  But until that day, this might still be a viable option for date compares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this; the formula goes into `row_1` (e.g. `X1`)*

```js
=vstack(
        "Header",
        map(indirect("D2:D"),lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,sum(hour(Σ)*3600,minute(Σ)*60,second(Σ)))))
        )
```